# HTML - Saving input data

Tags: html, forms, web, input, raspberry-pi

I am planning on making a raspberry pi web server to run a html default web page. I want this page to simply have an input form and a submit button. upon submission, the data in the input field should be saved to a text file, located on the raspberry pi. Any idea how to do so without php/mysql?

Comment: you need a server side language if you want to store data on the server

Comment: This is the purpose of PHP and MySQL databases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the purpose of the [server side scripting languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-side_scripting) .

But if you want to make something simple, and you mention you don't want to use PHP for this i suggest investigating this python example i have prepared for you :

```
from bottle import route, request, run

@route('/page')
def get_page():
    return '''
        <form action="/page" method="post">
            Enter data <input name="some-data" type="text" />
            <input value="Post" type="submit" />
        </form>
    '''


@route('/page', method='POST')
def post_page():
    data = request.forms.get('some-data')
    with open("somefile.txt", "w") as out_file:
        out_file.write(data)


run()
```

This code uses the minimalistic web framework called [Bottle](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/index.html) . After you run it, point your web browser to `http://127.0.0.1:8080/page` and when you click the `post` button the data from the text box will be saved to a local file.

**Notice:** this is a very simple example with no error handling and other important stuff , but it should help you get started in right direction .